# How to access SKU dimension fields with BigCommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using BigCommerce's v2 API. I notice in the BigCommerce control panel that users can enter depth, width, and height values for a specific SKU. However, the SKU api endpoint does not seem to return these fields. This is the response from the endpoint `/products/310/skus/10549`:

```
{
    "id": 10549,
    "product_id": 310,
    "sku": "testsku123",
    "price": null,
    "adjusted_price": "15.0000",
    "cost_price": "0.0000",
    "upc": "",
    "inventory_level": 0,
    "inventory_warning_level": 0,
    "bin_picking_number": "",
    "weight": null,
    "adjusted_weight": "4.5000",
    "is_purchasing_disabled": false,
    "purchasing_disabled_message": "",
    "image_file": "",
    "options": [{
        "product_option_id": 2292,
        "option_value_id": 3158
    }]
}
```

There are no fields for depth, width, or height, even though those values are set for this SKU in the control panel. Is there some other way to access these fields? Are there plans to make them available?

Answer (score 1):

You can access width, height and depth on the SKU level with the v3 API (that's the version of the API that's being consumed when you enter those dimensions on the SKU level through the control panel). Here's a link to the documentation on the v3 variable object:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/object-models.html#variant

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/catalog.html#getvariantbyid

Comment: Thanks. Is this page incorrectly linked?
 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/
 
If you click the "Using The V3 API" link, it brings you here:
 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#using-the-v3-api
 
Which is the same as the first page I linked to. Seems like something is misconfigured. Can someone look into this? I'm trying to read about how to get started with V3 but the link doesn't seem to be setup correctly.

Comment: Sorry about the broken link! The 'Using the v3 API' link should now be working.